# Syntax error, print with sep= statement

Tags: python, printing, jupyter-notebook, separator, jupyter

First and foremost i am very new into Python. I am using a notebook version of Ipython called jupyter and its provided by my University, so I don't know whether this is a standard version or not.

I was busy in a slide course about Python and encountered this exercice:

[image]

This is the code I used and the syntax error I get
in the Ipython environment

[image]

I don't get why it is not working.

Thank you in advance

Olivier

Comment: Does `print "Hello, World"` work in your environment? If so, you're using Python 2.7 or lower. That slide has 3.X code, and some syntax is incompatible.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering so quickly,  `print "Hello, World"` Works on my environment. How can i solve this syntax in order to let it work?

Comment: If you want to continue using a 3.X tutorial? Install Python 3.X and use that instead of what you have now.

Comment: i think i am obligated to stick to this version as we will use it for pyspark and big data purposes. Can you recommend me a good IPython 3.X environment to excercise in?  thx in advance

Comment: Most IDEs support both 2.7 and 3.X, so I assume you can keep using Jupyter for both. I'm guessing there's a setting you can adjust somewhere to toggle between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print([object, ...][, sep=' '][, end='\n'][, file=sys.stdout])` is a function in Python 3.x, which has a `sep` keyword argument (among others).

If you are using Python 2.7 (try `print "Hello!"` - if it runs, you have Python 2.x), `print` is a statement there, which means that if you want to get the behaviour as in your slide (make `print` a function), you need to import `print_function` from `__future__` module.

That way you can use `print("Hi!", "Hello!", sep='\t')` as in your slide.

As mentioned by @Kevin in his comment below this post, if your course uses Python 3.x, you would be better off to upgrade to this version since things like `async`, `yield from` or `lzma` are not available in Python 2.x.

Comment: importing print from the future is a good solution to the OP's current error, but I worry that he will continue to trip up as he follows along with those 3.X-only slides. What will he do when they cover `asyncio` or `yield from`?

Comment: @Kevin: thank you for your comment, I edited my post to include the suggestion to upgrade in case of these things.